# Export Distribution Groups, Members and Email Addresses

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get this command to list all distribution groups to include all email addresses (not just primary) and this works, although I'd like it comma delimited instead of space delimited if possible.

The only thing that's missing are the Members which I'd also like to include the in the results. Can someone tell me how to do that?

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Resultsize unlimited | Select Name,PrimarySmtpAddress,
  @{L="EmailAddresses";E={$_.EmailAddresses | ? {$_.PrefixString -ceq "smtp"} | % {$_.SmtpAddress}}} | 
    Export-Csv c:\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Essentially I should have the required values for all these columns:

```
DG Name, Primary SMTP Address, Email Addresses (comma delimited), Members (comma delimited)
```

If not too difficult, it'd be nice to display all the comma-delimited results in one cell for each DG (or some way that's easy to read).

Comment: A comma-delimited list within a CSV cell is not going to play nicely with the default delimiter. The only way to make that work is to make the CSV itself not comma-delimited. Can you give some direction on your delimiter requirements?

Comment: Ok don't worry about the comma delimeter. A space or tab delimiter will also work since I'm just going to use the Text To Columns feature in Excel (that's what I do now with the command I posted).

Comment: Either (temporarily) change the automatic variable `$OFS` = output field separator to `","` or enclose the expression in parentheses and append `-join ','` See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` or view [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you are doing for EmailAddresses works without issues, I chose the semi-colon (`;`) as the email address and member separator. `Members` will be the `PrimarySmtpAddress` value of each member. Feel free to change as is required.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Resultsize unlimited | Select Name,PrimarySmtpAddress,
  @{L="EmailAddresses";E={($_.EmailAddresses | ? {$_.PrefixString -ceq "smtp"} | % {$_.SmtpAddress}}) -join ';'},
  @{L="Members";E={(Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity).PrimarySmtpAddress -join ';'}} | 
    Export-Csv c:\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This query will become slower the larger your distribution group list grows because of the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` call for every group.